# SQLAlchemy stops working with MySQLdb out of nowhere

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

For the past couple days, it's been working fine. But today, I was trying fix some encoding issue, and it just suddenly stopped working. I reverted my code back to what it was like from before, but for some reason the error is still there. (And so is the encoding issue, sadly.)

I am using MySQL with MySQLdb on Python 3.6.2 and Anaconda. I am aware of MySQLdb's incompatibility with Python 3 and with Anaconda. However, I do not want to use Python 2 or a different driver.

I have worked around this by installing `mysqlclient`, and I am able to do `import MySQLdb` in the Qt console. I was also able to create an engine with below code literally 30 minutes ago.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/db?charset=utf8')
```

I checked my code with the one I had on the remote repo just to make sure there was no mistake. It's *exactly* the same. Yet now I'm getting the following error:

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql
```

Which seems very odd considering that I have both. This error is seen when I run my script in the Qt console with `%run myscript.py`. I've been doing that since yesterday without any issues.

I am not using any virtual environments as I found it a pain to manage them on Windows and with Anaconda. I also checked that `MySQLdb` is importable in the console before running the script. So I know the module is properly installed.

I tried to figure out what's going on, and during my investigation I found out that I'm missing `sqlalchemy.connectors` module, but I'm not sure if that actually is an issue because I can't find any similar issues online. Here's what I did to get that error:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.connectors'
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? This is really frustrating because this seems to be completely out of blue :/

** I just tested whether other drivers work (i.e. `pymysql`), and it doesn't. I think it's because `sqlalchemy` is rejecting the dialect regardless of the driver.

EDIT: To reproduce (at least on my machine at the moment) I only need 2 lines.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/db')
```

EDIT2: I identified it as an Anaconda issue, however I'm still unsure what the cause is.

Comment: Did you name something in your project folder `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: @KlausD. No, it's a small project and I've kept track of all namespaces. I just checked and there are exactly 3 mentions of `sqlalchemy` and that is within only one module, and in the `import` statements. Even then, I'm using the `from ... import ...` format, so `sqlalchemy` is not found in any namespaces.

Comment: I mean: is there a file or folder with that name?

Comment: @KlausD. No. There are only 4 files and 1 folder in this project so I'm fairly certain haha

Answer (score 0):

Clean reinstall of `sqlalchemy` have fixed the issue.
Can't believe that wasn't the first thing I tried.
I still have no idea how it got corrupted, though.

```
$ conda uninstall sqlalchemy
$ conda install sqlalchemy
```